# Is Superclass Object created everytime a subclass is instantiated?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, constructor

This is a two part question :

***PART #1 :***

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Main Started");
        Child c = new Child();          //Instantiating Child Class
        System.out.println("Main Ended");
    }

}

class Father{

    Father(){                           //Father Class Default Constructor
        System.out.println("I am in Father");
    }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class Child extends Father{

    Child(){                            //Child Class Default Constructor
        System.out.println("I am in Child");
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Main Started
I am in Father
I am in Child
Main Ended
```

This is what i know is happening at compile time

```
class Child extends Father{

    Child(){                            //Child Class Default Constructor
        super();
        System.out.println("I am in Child");
    }
}
```

here my question is, since it is going to the default constructor of the `Father` Class before executing the default constructor of `Child` Class, is there an object created for `Father`?

if so, then what is it getting assigned to? or is it similar to anonymous object like `new Father();`. Is an `Object` created **EVERYTIME** a constructor is called?

***PART #2***

Every single time i create an object for the `Child` Class, the default constructor of the `Father` Class will be called using `super();` within `Child()`.

What will happen when I am trying to invoke any method from `Father` using the `Child` object? will it again create an anonymous object for `Father`, use the object for execution then leave it for `Garbage Collector` to take care of?

Because of so, wouldn't this lead to tons of memory wastage simply because we tried to access the members of supper class multiple times.

How will the memory management take place in the above mentioned scenario?

Comment: This misconception is often caused by fact that people think that constructor *creates* object. It is not true, it only *initialize* (set up) object which was already created by `new` operator (yes, `new` keyword creates object first, *then* after it was created is calling constructor's code to properly set it up).

Comment: @Pshemo so what does this *SET UP* for the object mean exactly.

Comment: Before we let object be used, we want to make sure that it was properly set up. By that I mean ensuring that *its fields* hold values which "make sense" for application. For instance object of `File` class should *always* hold *some* info about location of file (or directory). Allowing us to use instance of File *without* such information (if that field holds `null`) would be designers mistake so Java has `File(String path){..}` constructor *via* which we can pass location (correct or even incorrect, as long as it "makes sense" for us/application). Only then File instance can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `Child` instance you aren't creating an **additional** `Father` instance. The `Child` instance **is also** a `Father` instance, since `Child` extends `Father`. `Child` is a specific type of `Father`.

One neat way of showing this is to print [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) in both classes, and seeing that both the `Father` and the `Chilld` constructors relate to the same memory address:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Main Started");
        Child c = new Child();          //Instantiating Child Class
        System.out.println("Main Ended");
    }

}

class Father{

    Father(){                           //Father Class Default Constructor
        System.out.println("I am in Father in address " + System.identityHashCode(this));
    }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class Child extends Father{

    Child(){                            //Child Class Default Constructor
        System.out.println("I am in Child in address " + System.identityHashCode(this));
    }
}
```

And an example output:

```
Main Started
I am in Father in address 2001049719
I am in Child in address 2001049719
Main Ended
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for the example. Just one more thing, and this is in context to the example you have given above. So, in inheritance, even though the `Super Class` constructor is called, but its object is not created. Is this Accurate?

Comment: @404BrainNotFound There is only *one* object, it is of `Child` *class*, but at the same time of `Father` *type* and that object already exist when constructors code is executed (which is why we can use `this` inside constructors to refer to such object).

Comment: One thing I still can't get it is how you can access the properties of parent class if the object of parent is not created ?

Comment: The child instance *is* (also) a parent instance. Let's take a concrete example - the parent class is "Human" and the child class is "Fireman". A Fireman is a specific kind of human, but he's still a human - he has arms, legs and a face. He can walk, talk, eat and sleep like any human does. The difference is that he adds another method, `putOutFire()`.